# Delete all but n most recent files?

Tags: windows, gratis, logs

I need a good tool, preferably a purpose-built, not a Swiss Army knife, and definitely free.

The tool will only allow a maximum number of files - or maybe files of a certain wildcard match - in a folder and delete all but the max (n) newest files by date updated.

I have a lot of log files accumulating that are pretty huge so I only want to keep a couple around at a time.

Comment: Sounds like a problem needing to be solved at the source; most logging frameworks have a built-in option for rotating log files. Of course, if you can't change/configure that, you'll need another solution ...